# AngularJS & Node.JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, software-design

everyone!
I have the following inquiry: Is it possible to have a mirror programming?

I mean the following:

```
    /* This are models ( MVC ) */

Client & Server
MyApp{
var DATA = array();
const SIDE = true // current side. On the server const SIDE = false

    // Directive Content
    function Content(){

        // Directive Title
        function Title(){

            $DATA['Content']['Title'] = function(){

                var fromWhere = URL//From where it takes the lead

                // Maybe a good idea to put in setInterval
                $.get(fromWhere) ...

                    $scope.title = $data['title'];
                    if(SIDE){
                        Here works front end
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to write a code and the outside and inside.The parts that relate to the side (front / back) to switch.

Is it possible to make the program fully mirror? - Outside and inside
Only certain properties are defined different.

Answer (score 0):

[Strongloop](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK;jsessionid=5FDF2D3E548B2A5D0EAB78F489A8D803) promises to do that.

[DerbyJS](http://derbyjs.com/) Does something similar too.

[Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) Promises isomorphic stack.

Does that answer your question properly? :)